# How to solve : library not found for -lgcov

Tags: gcov

Here is my environment

```
c++ --version

Apple clang version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

```
gcov --version

Apple LLVM version 13.1.6 (clang-1316.0.21.2.5)
  Optimized build.
  Default target: arm64-apple-darwin21.4.0
  Host CPU: vortex
```

I try to collect coverage on my M1 Mac. However, when I invoke `c++ -lgcov`, it said:
`ld: library not found for -lgcov`, where can I find the lib and link?

Comment: Do you not know how to use your OS to search for files?

Comment: I'm not familiar with these. Which file should I search for? How do I use the file? Please suggest

Comment: ??? The missing `gcov`, of course. Do you not know how to use your operating system's search functionality? If you don't know the basics of using your OS, shouldn't you learn how to use your computer before you start trying to write programs?

Comment: I mean, I'm not familiar with gcov and its lib. Now `lgcov` require the library, which concrete library is missing? I can search if I know which file I should search for.

Comment: If 'libgcov.a' is the name of the lib file name, it's missing on my Mac

Comment: `-l` means `link`, and the text that follows is the base name of the library that should be linked. You can search for `gcov*` using the search functionality of your operating system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Library not found for lgcov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059961/library-not-found-for-lgcov)